# How do I define object-references between tables in object-relational database feature of oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I successfully created an EmployeeType in Oracle 11g with the following atrributes;

```
emp_id   VARCHAR2(5)
title   VARCHAR(15)
firstname VARCHAR(20)
surname   VARCHAR(20)
address Addresstype
tel_no  ARRAY(3) of VARCHAR(15)
get_address() VARCHAR2()
```

and was told to create DepartmentType in Oracle 11g with the following attributes

```
dept_id  VARCHAR2(3)
location AddressType
manager  REF Employee
```

but my problem now is I don't know how to use the object-relational REF construct to define object-references between the two tables for relating Departments to Employees so that I can create table which will store department details and insert rows.

Comment: What language you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some ORM (Object Relational Mapping) frameworks you can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs316/ref_guide_mapping.html)

[What is an Object-Relational Mapping Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152299/what-is-an-object-relational-mapping-framework)

That is a huge topic, or you can manage to find a way to do it yourself, but what you must know is that relational database are just rows with data, nothing to do with Object Oriented Object, you can take it as a way to store data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I created the DepartmentType with the following command   CREATE TYPE DepartmentType as OBJECT
(
dept_id VARCHAR2(3),
locations AddressType,
manager REF EmployeeType
)NOT FINAL;  but when I tried using the following command INSERT INTO department VALUES 
(D01, AddressType(47, 'Canal Street', 'Manchester', 'MR8 9WR'),
(SELECT REF(e) FROM EMPLOYEE e WHERE emp_id = 2)); to insert rows into the department table I got an error saying 'Column not allowed here'. Please I really need solution on this problem.

Comment: @chidoskychidosky Your insert works for me if I add single quotation marks around `D01`.

Comment: @ Jonearles Thank you very much. The way I referenced the two tables is it correct?

Comment: Please how do I join the Employee and department table by the use object references.

Comment: How do I display the contents in the array in the Employee table above?

Comment: To answer your join question start reading from : 
`Creating References to View Objects` you will have to use `REF ` modifier
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76976/adobjvew.htm

But I think your making it harder by dealing with object references.