# How to rewrite SQL query to LINQ (using GroupBy, Distinct)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question on mind for a few long days.
Finally, I made a SQL query, which I want to show in MVC4 View.
I build following SQL query:

```
select distinct date, max(priority) from Timetables where date between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-31' group by date
```

which returns me a collection of dates and max priorities of that dates. That is OK for me. I am totaly okay, when this query returns me a whole Timetables record.
But I need to pass result of this query to View engine of MVC4. 
I had some tries, but I am nowhere near finding a result for that.
If you have some other possibilities, how to do that, I am eager to hear :)

Also, I am using an Entity Framework.

Thanks!

e:
The database looks like that:

```
id  | doctor_id  | nurse_id  | date    | start_time  | end_time |time_for_pacient| priority |comments
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-01| 07:00       | 11:30    |   00:20        |    1     |Normal
2   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-02| 07:00       | 11:30    |   00:20        |    1     |Normal
3   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-01| 08:00       | 10:30    |   00:20        |    2     |Shorten
4   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-02| 06:00       | 10:30    |   00:10        |    3     |Extra
```

the result I want to achieve in View:

```
id  | doctor_id  | nurse_id  | date    | start_time  | end_time |time_for_pacient| priority |comments
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-01| 08:00       | 10:30    |   00:20        |    2     |Shorten
4   |     5      |   4       | 13-12-02| 06:00       | 10:30    |   00:10        |    3     |Extra
```

I just want to show a single record for each day with highest priority.

Comment: well the distinct is redundant for starters, group by takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

With EntityFramework and other [ORM tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152299/what-is-an-object-relational-mapping-framework), don't think of selecting specific fields or columns. Rather, you're selecting specific obejcts.

To translate your exact query to LINQ would actually end up returning a collection of anonymous objects which is rarely what you want.

In C#, it might look like this:

```
var date1 = new Date(2013, 12, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2013, 12, 31);
var timetables = DbContext.Timetables
                     .Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(date1) >= 0 && x.Date.CompareTo(date2) <= 0)
                     .Distinct();
```

Comment: Pretty nice thought. If I can introduce you more deeply into the problem, I show you an example: I want to show records of days in range from 2013-12-01 to 2013-12-31. But in every day, they could be more records, but with different priority. I want to select only one record for each day (that one with highest priority). See edit on my question, there is a look on database, how it does look like and how I want to see that.